# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha actual del sistema (DateTime) y convertirla a un double? C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación sobre la cual es necesario desplegar un reloj que muestre la hora actual. Para ello implemento los siguientes métodos:

```
    private void InicializaActual()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        ta = DateTime.Now.ToOADate();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ta++;
        TiempoActual.Text = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, (int)ta).ToString();
    }
```

Sin embargo, no me despliega la hora actual, si no que siempre marca que son las 12:19:00 y creo que debe ser por el método de ToOADate();
Alguna forma de convertir la hora actual en un doble?
Gracias de antemano:)

Comment: No entiendo que estas tratando de mostrar... TimeSpan es un intervalo de tiempo.. vos que queres mostrar?

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo, quizás no fui muy claro. Explico, quiero mostrar un reloj con la hora actual que obviamente cada segundo cambie. Para ello primero mediante el método InicializaActual creo el timer con un intervalo de 1 segundo, que estará ejecutando el método timer_Tick el cual solo incrementa el valor obtenido de la hora actual en +1 y lo despliega en un TextBox

Comment: PEro es totalmente innecesario hacer todo eso.. como el tick de un timer, por mas que pongas cada 1 segundo, no se va a ejecutar exactamente cada un segundo, te alcanza con que en cada tick del timer muestres de vuelta la hora actual...

Comment: igual, no deberias usar timespan.. deberias agregarle un segundo al objeto datetime que obtuviste en el principio

Comment: De hecho, así lo intente en un inicio. Solo añadiéndole un segundo al DateTime en cada tick, el problema que en ocasiones se generaba un cierto delay y se me desfasaba con otro timer que tengo por lo que busque otra opción

Comment: porque el que desfasa, es el timer.. entonces esta solucion que planteas tambien se va a desfasar.. lo que tenes que hacer, repito, es tomar la hora en cada tick. tu otro timer, no se que hace, pero lo que vos queres hacer aca no es correcto.. te va a pasar exactamente lo mismo....

Comment: Entonces el metodo del tick solo tomaria nuevamente la fecha, y la desplegaria? public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            TiempoActual.Text = time.ToString("");
        }

Comment: Me parece tu mejor opcion. lo probaste?

Answer (score 0):

**Para obtener la hora actual y que cambie como un reloj real junto con la fecha puedes hacer esto**

Suponiendo que estás pensando en algo así
[image: Suponiendo que estas pensando en algo asi]

```
    En el método load del formulario inicializamos nuestro timer 
    y puedes capturar la hora y fecha en el formato que desees

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
        textBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
    }

    Y en el timer_Tick
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

[Aquí hay una respuesta para convertir a double la fecha capturada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827569/string-variable-date-to-double-in-c-sharp)

Comment: que es justamente todo lo que esta escrito en los comentarios ;)... igual, sobra un timer1.Start()....